# Can't start Spotify due to permissions

Tags: permissions, chromebook, spotify

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I'm unable to open Spotify. I have a Chromebook and am using Crouton. The error I'm getting is this:

```
[1117/164602.540507:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(254)] Failed to adjust OOM score of renderer with pid 17351: Permission denied
```

I feel like there must be an easy answer but I'm still just learning the ropes. Thanks to anyone who can help. 
I also got something similar when I was using Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with a (fairly) recent version of Chrome.  Please see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211616 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576409

One poster mentioned that by downloading the current .deb file from chrome, and installing it using `sudo apt-get ...` that they were able to make Chrome work again, so I would suggest thatthis may fix your issue.